# How to adapt to a kubernetes path change in Python Flask routes

Tags: python-3.x, flask, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I have a Python Flask app I've deployed on IBM Kubernetes Service. My deployment YAML specifies `path: /`, which is handled in my code with `@app.route('/')`. That works fine. I then attempted to move the app by changing `path: /` to `path: /foo` in my deployment YAML. I was expecting the request coming into my app to still come in as `/`, but it's coming in as `/foo`. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is to be flexible in the deployment of the app without having the change source code. I don't see a way in either Kubernetes or Flask to create this level of indirection. Am I missing something?

Original YAML:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - my....us-east.containers.appdomain.cloud
    secretName: my...
  rules:
  - host: my....us-east.containers.appdomain.cloud
    http:
      paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: my-service
           servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: What are you using for the ingress controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to check the content of your `ingress` yaml definition.

Here's an example `yaml` definition with rewrites

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:

```
rewrite.bar.com/something rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/
rewrite.bar.com/something/ rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/
rewrite.bar.com/something/new rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/new
```

You can check Nginx Ingress controller Rewrite annotations [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). You can also customize Ingress routing with annotations on IBM Cloud following the [documentation here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress_annotation)

Comment: The `rewrite-path` was what I was asking for and what I thought I needed. I added a this statement to my annotations and URLs `/foo/*` now resolve to `/*`.  That re-write causes breakage with things like stylesheets, other static files, and URLs on HTML forms. To fix those URLs, I need to inject the `/foo` to cause the URL to be re-written correctly. I added my ingress yaml above.

Comment: To the original YAML I added an annotation, `ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: "serviceName=my-service rewrite=/"` and change the backend path to `/foo`.

Comment: Glad you are able to achieve what you wanted with rewrites